# How do I add MP3, MP4 and H.264 support to Chromium on Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, mp3, chromium, mp4

Google Chrome on Windows comes with support for the above media formats, however, Chromium does not.

I want to add support for my own personal use, how can I do this?

I know that on Ubuntu this is solvable by installing the `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` and `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-nonfree` packages, however I didn't find anything for Windows.

Comment: You have to copy avcodec*.dll files from Chrome installation to Chromium. http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/06/24/play-embedded-mp3-audio-files-chromium/ -- I wonder if [k-lite codec pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm) installation would fix this..

Comment: @medigeek - Why is that a comment rather than an answer (assuming you have tested it and are confident it solves the problem)?

Comment: You assume correctly, I don't have a windows pc at the moment :)

Comment: @medigeek - Fair enough.  The source seems legit - but fair enough :)

Comment: @medigeek - Looks like Chrome no longer uses those av*.dll files, since I'm not seeing them in the folder. Replacing `ffmpegsumo.dll` (the Chrome version is bigger) also doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I'm making this comment so that next time I come here I can hopefully notice the k-lite comment (instead of the solved answer below)...

Answer (score 11):

Google has little incentive to support H.264 when they have their own, competing [WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) [format](http://www.webmproject.org/) that they are trying to push. (Haven’t you ever wondered why such a relatively unknown format is one of the formats the YouTube, a Google subsidiary, supports natively?)

Unfortunately, as you have learned, they re-structured Chromium so that you cannot easily drop in H.264 support as you could before. In fact, they have been [planning](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/01/more-about-chrome-html-video-codec.html) on dropping support for H.264 altogether (even from Chrome) for a couple of years. They plan on switching completely to the WebM by providing WebM plugins for other browsers. (Hopefully they will continue to support JPG and PNG despite trying to push their [WebP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) [format](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/).)

What you can try instead, is to use the [Microsoft plugin](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/wmp-extension-for-chrome) that lets Chromium play H.264 through Windows Media Player. Because it is a plugin, it should still work—unless Google specifically blocked it.

Comment: `Hopefully they will continue to support JPG and PNG ...`. Haha, +1

Comment: Windows Media Player HTML5 Extension for Chrome
This extension is deprecated and no longer available for download.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how this is done, but [Advanced Chrome](http://browser.taokaizen.com/) fork does support MP3/MP4/H.264. Check it out!

Comment: This is nice... they distibute pre-compiled binaries with no installer. Just unzip and run! Tested h264 support and it works out of the box.